# I need to extract data from files from an old sensor but I don't recognize the format, encoding or symbols

Tags: python, encoding, binary

I need to extract data from raw files from water sensors, but I don't recognize the characters or encoding.

Files come directly from the sensor in plain text and have no extension or description,
**the output should be numbers separated by commas.**

**original example**:

„ ÈB9ÿ¤ÿ  Þÿ  Rþc ³

…  rB<ÿ¤ÿ  ßÿ  Sþb ±

„ nC<ÿ¤ÿ  àÿ   Rþb ±

„ ê?<ÿ¤ÿ  àÿ  Qþe µ

...

**expected**:

-0.339795,0.1001767,0.0101992,-4.27,14.52512,846.7311,0,0,657.7027,0,-1.99,-0.92,29.96391,15.0126,-53.029,0,0,0

-0.3384331,1.082728E-2,0.0514378,-4.3,14.49225,845.3952,0,0,657.6309,0,-1.96,-0.92,29.96391,15.0126,-53.029,0,0,0

...

Is there a way to make this text readable?

Here is a link to a repository with one file in the original format, and one "converted" using the software from the Station (EcoFlux)

files: https://github.com/alejandrogandara/station_files.git

Comment: It's probably that binary data is being interpreted as characters. There are no characters or encoding, probably - you should be using a hex editor to look at the data and see what you can learn. Plenty of hex editors allow you to interpret data as different types, so you can see if the data is being encoded as, say, floats or doubles. Looking at raw binary data as text is like trying to understand the code of a game disc by playing its data in a CD player and trying to listen to the audio that comes out. It's just random static. Same with the "characters" you're looking at. I think.

Comment: Yes @Random Davis, that is the problem. I tried all the encodings in python, and also Notepad++ HEX-Editor, and... nothing useful.

Comment: I think you probably would need to spend more time in a hex editor. As well as making sure that the data is not being corrupted somehow; for instance, if you're on Windows, and saving the data as text, it could be that an end-of-line conversion is being done. As in, any 0x0A sequences are replaced with two bytes, 0x0D and 0x0A. Just one possibility. You probably need to play around with byte order, alignment, etc. Also figure out exactly how many bytes it takes for the pattern to repeat. How many bytes is the data? Depending on the size, that can say quite a bit about what the data represents.

Comment: The point of a binary file is that it doesn't have or need an encoding. It doesn't contain characters.

Comment: Give it an eye to the files @Mark Ransom, there is a link to a repository with one file in the original format, and one "converted" using the software from the Station (EcoFlux), 

I have 50k files left to convert.

Comment: Are you sure those files correspond to each other?  I tried a bunch of likely conversions and didn't get anywhere.

Comment: If those values are coming from a sensor, there's a good possibility that they're integers. Thus offsets and scaling are applied. Without an exact correspondence between input and output it will be impossible to figure those out.